# My son has scratched my wok. Now it's rusting. Can it be restored or should I throw it away?

Tags: wok

It says Made in Japan. It's heavy and matte black. Can't post the pic due to size limitations.

Comment: *Can't post the pic due to size limitations.* There are plenty of online services where you can shrink the image.

Comment: Without knowing whether the wok is non-stick or not, this question is essentially un-answerable.  Ther are comments implying this under the answers, which haven't been address in two days.  VTC.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can restore it.

Clean the whole wok. Wash with soap and dry it. Apply a small coat of oil and put it on high. Let it burn (ventilate the kitchen).

Repeat the process of applying a small coat of oil and putting it on high another two or three times.

Done.

**Edit:** As noted by @GdD, this method cannot be applied to non-stick woks.

Comment: You're assuming this isn't a non-stick wok, that's bad advice for one of those.

Comment: Right you are, @GdD! Non-stick woks are garbage.

Comment: They are, but if the OP has one then they shouldn't do what you say.

Comment: Non-sticks shouldn't rust in the first place....

Comment: The method is called *seasoning*, as in "seasoning the pan". There are several tutorials online, including recommendations on what kind of oil to use.

Comment: @noumenal A non-stick pan can rust if it's scratched.

Comment: @Cindy True. The alloys made for non-stick pans reduce the probability of oxidation. However, when the coating is broken they will eventually rust. They *can* rust, but they "shouldn't". At that stage it is maybe better to throw them away.

Answer (score 1):

Given the cost of most asian wok, it would be more cost effective to purchase a new one than restoring a damaged wok. Assuming it's not-non-stick or not-coated, you can season the wok as if it's a carbon steel or cast iron pan. Scrub off the rust in hot water until water is clear; then best with non processed oil like animal fat or lard frying with onion and perhaps some salt under high heat until the wok turns dark.

Comment: High heat should not be used with non-stick coatings.

Comment: Certainly not when empty, and with intent to season the vessel.

Comment: @Cindy My fault on the typo. I meat not-non-stick. But I have never heard of seasoning a non-stick pan either if there were ever such thing as seasoning non-stick to be mistaken...

Comment: Thanks for editing! You can 'season' non-stick cookware but it is a very different procedure and does not use high heat as you would with bare metal.

Answer (score 0):

Use Crisco to season your wok.  Also, a little rust can be rinsed away and the wok will eventually season itself if you avoid metal scrubbers and clean it with a bamboo wok brush and remember to dry it and just keep using it over time.